# Problem with WatiN and Nunit

Tags: nunit, watin

I'm following this [WatiN - Get Started tutorial video](http://watin.org/documentation/getting-started/), I'm having 2 problems

1 - I don't get the "green" points on the vertical bar (where breakpoints appear), to run the dll how he/she does.

Since I can't "run" the dll, I created a webApplication, added the class library to this application and I'm calling the function on a `btnClick` event

The 2nd problem is, I'm getting the following error when I click the button,

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.SHDocVw, Version=1.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The "green points" are from JetBrains ReSharper - they allow you to run the unit test in ReSharper's Test Runner.
In relation to the 2nd point, select the project's reference to SHDocVw and press F4 (properties).  Set "Embed Interop Type" to false - this will enable copy local too.  When you build you'll get a compiler warning, suggesting you change it back - but hey!